How can I use await or promise on MySQL call in Twilio serverless functions?
I am using two serverless functions within the Twilio console that call each other to make a openai-powered voice chat. The first, /transcribe,  is triggered by an incoming call.  I make a successful MySQL call in /transcribe, but can’t seem to get the script to wait for it to finish.  /transcribe keeps running and calls /respond which handles calls to openai and then calls back to /transcribe to continue the conversation.  The MySQL data is not received in time to set important values in the script. And that's the challenge.
What I’d like to learn more about is what does Twilio want to see in this structure to pause the script long enough to complete the MySQL call and use the values in the /transcribe function?  Await & promise? Some other method that has the same effect?  Happy to go study and report back.
Here's much of the /transcribe function:
{
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    if (!event.request.cookies.convo) { //if no conversation is present
        getDbRow((error, users) => {
       //here’s where I want to assign values needed by the rest of the script
    }); // end of db call
    // Greet the user with a message  
    twiml.say({
                voice: 'Polly.Joanna-Neural',
            }, 
           “Howdy”
        );
    } // end of “if no conversation “

    // Listen to the user's speech and pass the input to the /respond Function
    twiml.gather({
        speechTimeout: 'auto', // Automatically determine the end of user speech
        speechModel: 'experimental_conversations', // Use the conversation-based speech recognition model
        input: 'speech', // Specify speech as the input type
        action: '/respond', // Send the collected input to /respond 
    });
    // Create a Twilio Response object
    const response = new Twilio.Response();
    // Set the response content type to XML (TwiML)
    response.appendHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    // Set the response body to the generated TwiML
    response.setBody(twiml.toString())
    response.setCookie('first_system_prompt', encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(openai_system_prompt))); 

    // If no conversation cookie is present, set an empty conversation cookie
    if (!event.request.cookies.convo) {
        response.setCookie('convo', '', ['Path=/']); 
    }
    // Return the response to Twilio
    return callback(null, response);
};  // end of exports.handler for /transcribe

//then my database function which takes about 0.2 seconds to resolve

function getDbRow(callback) {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'testHere',
        user: 'testHere',
        password: ''testHere'',
        database: ''testHere''
    });


    connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
            return callback(err, null);
        }
        console.log('Connected to the database.');


        const query = 'SELECT first_name, system_prompt, summary_last_conversation FROM test WHERE id=1';
       
        connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error('Error executing query:', error);
                connection.end();
                return callback(error, null);
            }
            connection.end((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error closing the connection:', err);
                }
                console.log('Connection closed.');
            });
            callback(null, results);
        });
    });
}

/respond has an async exports.handler  and once done with openai, calls /transcribe, and so it repeats.  Here is the roughstructure of the /respond function:
// Import the OpenAI module using CommonJS syntax
const OpenAI = require("openai");
// since console.log doesn't seem to work well, let's make the openai system prompt very 
// different to debug if the cookie comes over
let initial_system_prompt = "You are a polite professor, teaching facts about history.";

// Define the main function for handling requests
exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
    try {
        // Set up the OpenAI API client with the API key from your environment variables
        const openai = new OpenAI.OpenAIApi(new OpenAI.Configuration({
            apiKey: context.OPENAI_API_KEY,
        }));
        // Set up the Twilio VoiceResponse object to generate the TwiML
        const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
        // Initiate the Twilio Response object to handle updating the cookie with the chat history
        const response = new Twilio.Response();
        // Parse the cookie value if it exists
        const cookieValue = event.request.cookies.convo;
        const cookieData = cookieValue ? JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(cookieValue)) : null;
        // Now I attempt to use the cookie values I sent over
        const cookieValuePrompt = event.request.cookies.first_system_prompt;
        if (cookieValuePrompt) {
            try {
               initial_system_prompt = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(cookieValuePrompt));
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error parsing first_system_prompt cookie:', error);
            // If there's an error parsing, we'll keep the default initial_system_prompt
             }
        }

        // Get the user's voice input from the event
        let voiceInput = event.SpeechResult;

        // Create a conversation object to store the dialog and the user's input to the conversation history
        const conversation = cookieData?.conversation || [];
        conversation.push({ role: 'user', content: voiceInput });

        // Get the AI's response based on the conversation history
        const aiResponse = await generateAIResponse(conversation, openai);

        // Add the AI's response to the conversation history
        conversation.push({ role: 'assistant', content: aiResponse });

        // Limit the conversation history to the last 20 messages
        while (conversation.length > 20) {
            conversation.shift();
        }

        // Generate some <Say> TwiML using the cleaned up AI response
        twiml.say({
            voice: "Polly.Joanna-Neural",
        },
            aiResponse
        );

        // Redirect to the Function where the <Gather> is capturing the caller's speech
        twiml.redirect({
            method: "POST",
        },
            `/transcribe`
        );

        // Since we're using the response object to handle cookies we can't just pass the TwiML straight back to the callback, we need to set the appropriate header and return the TwiML in the body of the response
        response.appendHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        response.setBody(twiml.toString());

        // Update the conversation history cookie with the response from the OpenAI API
        const newCookieValue = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
            conversation
        }));
        response.setCookie('convo', newCookieValue, ['Path=/']);

        // Return the response to the handler
        return callback(null, response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in handler:", error);
        return callback(error);
    }
};

// Function to generate the AI response based on the conversation history
async function generateAIResponse(conversation, openai) {
    const messages = formatConversation(conversation);
    return await createChatCompletion(messages, openai);
}

// Function to create a chat completion using the OpenAI API
async function createChatCompletion(messages, openai) {
    try {
        // Define system messages to model the AI

        const systemMessages = [{
            role: "system",
            content:  initial_system_prompt
        }
        ];
        messages = systemMessages.concat(messages);


        const chatCompletion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
            model: 'gpt-4',
            messages: messages,
            temperature: 0.8,
            max_tokens: 100,
            top_p: 0.9,
            n: 1,
        });
        if (chatCompletion.data.choices[0].message.content && 
            chatCompletion.data.choices[0].message.content.toLowerCase().includes("toasted shrimp")) {
        // do stuff
        }
        return chatCompletion.data.choices[0].message.content;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during OpenAI API request:", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

// Function to format the conversation history
function formatConversation(conversation) {
    return conversation.map(message => ({
        role: message.role,
        content: message.content
    }));
}


Helpful folks have suggested making the exports.handler an await function(). Twilio doesn’t like that and it times out. Using await in a synchronous function isn’t good.  Others have suggested using a callback to signal that it’s done.  That didn’t work. There was some work to make the MySQL call a promise, but this failed as well (perhaps because I didn’t get the syntax right).
Is there a best practice for making a MySQL call in this environment that can populate fields before the script runs on?

You are going to need to return a new promise with resolve and reject as arguments to the anonymous function definition which will contain the body of code from your function that now returns the promise.
Inside just call reject(error) on MySQL error.   Or call resolve(results) to resolve the promise.   Since your function returns a promise object.
You can now chain the method.then() and pass in to that chained method a function definition and declare a statement what to do next.  That way you wait for promise resolution then you proceed to the next step.

That did the trick.  Thank you!  I'll post the updated DB call function in case it helps others.

Thanks @Vahe for getting me on the right track.  Here is the modified DB function that returns a new promise:
   function getDbRowPromise() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const connection = mysql.createConnection({
           host: 'test',
           user: 'test',
           password: 'test',
           database: 'test'
       });

       connection.connect((err) => {
           if (err) {
               console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
               reject(err);
               return;
           }
           console.log('Connected to the database.');
           const query = 'SELECT first_name, system_prompt, summary_last_conversation FROM test WHERE id=1';
           connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
               connection.end();
               if (error) {
                   console.error('Error executing query:', error);
                   reject(error);
               } else {
                   resolve(results);
               }
           });
       });
   });
} 

Here is how it is called in the exports.handler:
    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    
        function processDbResults(users) {
           if (users && users.length > 0) {
              const { first_name, this_value, that_value } = users[0];
              // assign values
            } else {
            console.log('No results found for id=1.');
            } 

This works perfectly and I hope it helps others.
